# Why does print again and again forever?

Tags: java, for-loop

I couldn't figure out why my code is printing forever. I tried a block (will show where I had it originally) but I want it to continue after printing the "help". My code goes as follows. I think it's the for loop... but I haven't touched much on it.

```
boolean yes = true;

while(yes) {
    if(str1.equalsIgnoreCase("Exit")) {
        System.exit(0);
    } else if (str1.equalsIgnoreCase("Help")) {
        for(int g = 0; g < 2; g++) {
        System.out.println("    Accepted commands:\n    exit\n  help\n  load [filename]\n   students\n  search [partial name]\n assignments\n   grades\n    student [student name]\n    assignment [assignment name]\n");
        }
        //I added the break here and it did print out once but I did not want it to end the program. With the break I did not need the for statement.

    } else if (str1.equalsIgnoreCase("Load")) {

    }
```

Comment: You never change the value of `yes` or `str1` in the `while` loop

Comment: Your code, which won't even compile as is, never hits a logical case where it would break from the loop.  Is this really hard to understand?

Comment: Sorry I didn't start programming from inside the womb like you, Tim.

Answer (score 3):

The value of `str1` is never changed inside the loop. Perhaps you are missing some statement that takes new input from the user.

Comment: Thank you I had it in the wrong place is all

Answer (score 1):

First off

```
boolean yes = true;

while(yes) {
```

You are never setting `yes` to false

Secondly

```
 if(str1.equalsIgnoreCase("Exit")) {
        System.exit(0);
```

`str1` is never set inside the loop, even to `"Exit"`

Answer (score 0):

`yes` is set to true and you never changed it in the loop

Answer (score 0):

read str1 inside the loop:

```
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(System.in);
str1=in.readLine();

   while(true) {
       str1=in.readLine();
```